# How to express a list of objects with a common interface in C++

Tags: c#, c++, list, design-patterns, derived

I am struggling to express a list containing various derived class instances in a container object according to a common interface.  Adding them to a vector affords options, using the base class, pointers and references.  Casting them to concrete types using a discriminator is proving problematic later.

In C#, give or take, I would express it this way:

```
public interface IOrderable 
{
  decimal GetUnitPrice( );
}
public class BaseProduct 
{
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public decimal UnitPrice {get;set;}
  //
  public GetUnitPrice( return UnitPrice; }
}
public class Digital : BaseProduct, IOrderable
{
  public int Bytes {get;set;}
}
public class Physical : BaseProduct, IOrderable
{
  public int MassInGrammes {get;set}
}
public class Order
{
  public List<IOrderable> listOfItems;
  public int TotalBytes() 
  { 
     int t = 0;
     foreach( var i in listOfItems )
     { 
        var d = i as Digital;          // <-- in C# this patterny works fine 
        if( d != null ) t = t + d.Bytes;
     }
     return t;
  }
  public decimal TotalMass() { ... }
}
```

When I try to achieve this in C++, I begin with the base class, and create a vector.

```
class BaseProduct
{
public:
  string type;    // <-- discriminator
  etc.
}
class Order
{
public:
  vector<BaseProduct> listOfItems;
  int totalBytes() {
    int t=0;
    for( BaseProduct bp: listOfItems )
    {
      if( bp.type == "digital" )
       ... and this is where the wheels come off
           how to go from BaseProuct to Digital?
      if( bp.type == "physical" )
       ... etc.
    }
    return t;
  }
}
```

If I create a list based on pointers I can see how to reinterpret_cast to a known derived type.  This is my best guess.

I could not get a version with references to objects to work - the vector definition - closest was wrapped_reference<object&>.

I feel am making heavy weather of this, largely because of C++'s focus on object ownership/lifetime, and the general advice that pointers are somehow evil, even in modern C++.  (How things have changed!  C++ WAS pointer-land once!)

What then is a good (not necessarily best) pattern for this kind of mixed type list in C++?

*(Please note, the above is only pseudo code, the problem emerged in a knarly byte-level message parser, where there is one class per message type.  Two is enough to find a pattern.)*

Comment: unique_ptr is not evil, shared_ptr is not evil

Comment: That's probably me returning to C++ after 20yrs of C# where access to pointers is guarded by the "unsafe" compiler directive.  I am still adjusting.

Comment: Do you think vector<unique_ptr<BaseProduct>> is the way to go?  Would that allow the reinterpret_cast and be acceptable in terms of guarding against errors?

Comment: the equivalent of  c#'s 'as'  is dynamic_cast in c++

Comment: yes, vector unique_ptr is the way to go and you dont need a type field

Comment: I can work with that as a definition.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `std::vector<BaseObject>` contains only `BaseObject`s.  It can't hold any other type, no matter if it inherits from `BaseObject` or not.

Remember, in C++ variables aren't pointers or references unless you declare them to be.  That stands in contrast to C#, where all variables of class types are references to dynamically allocated objects.

To have polymorphism in C++ you must use (smart) pointers or references.  To fill a container with dynamically allocated objects of types derived from `BaseObject`, you'll likely want either a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseObject>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseObject>>`.

Which one you want depends on your needs:

- `std::unique_ptr` has less essentially no runtime overhead over a raw pointer, but is limited to unique ownership semantics.
- `std::shared_ptr` has shared ownership semantics more similar to C#'s garbage collected references, but entails some extra runtime overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the insight into C# vs C++ class declarations - a useful reminder.  Very used to C#'s classes-are-references in code.  The extra overhead, with shared_ptr, is assumed to be reference counting?

Comment: @S9DD Yes.  Also the reference counting is guaranteed to be thread-safe, and that thread-safety imposes some extra overhead.

Comment: This link may help others searching for an example of this working - see Example 4 on this page: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/how-to-create-and-use-shared-ptr-instances?view=msvc-170